# Android - package com.google.android.youtube.player does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I cant seem to compile my App in Androoid Studio, i am trying to use the Android Youtube Player API. I have included the AndroidYoutubePlayerApi.jar in my libs folder:

Here is what i have done:

build.gardle (Module:App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
        compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev125-1.19.1'
    }
```

Added user-permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But cant seem to compile and import com.google.android.*;

I have downloaded all the SDK Tools aswel.

Update:

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    }
```

Comment: I think you should required `com.google.android.gms:play-services`

Comment: MD: still no luck i added compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' but still does not compile

Comment: Try updating android studio... after this it will ask to fix old gradle plugin automatically

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it scores high on Google for this error message, so I thought I'd supply my solution here.

I'm using Android Studio to build an Ionic app that uses the YouTube player (by way of the cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player). This may not be identical to what other people are trying to do, but this solution may point them in the right direction.

I go to "File > Project Structure ..."
In the left-hand panel, there's a list of things. Under "Modules" is the name of the project I'm building ("app").
[image: View of the Project Structure dialog box]

Clicking on "app" and then clicking on the dependency tab, I manually add dependencies for the **YouTubeAndoridPlayerApi.jar** and **openyoutubeactivity.jar** as "implementation" dependencies.

[image: View of the dependencies tab]

Why the include of "*.jar" in the "libs" directory doesn't perform that include, I'm not sure. But when I added the dependencies explicitly, my project successfully compiles.